# Cannot load pre-sale Ethereum into Wallet

Tags: wallets, presale

I purchased pre-sale Ether and stayed on the sidelines until today. I downloaded the Win64 wallet installer from GitHub and installed on Windows 10.  It's running and syncing to the network.

It has a drop-box for the pre-sale ether wallet .json file.  I drop it there - enter the password, the import starts, the logo goes through cool graphics - then the wallet just crashes - disappears.  No process left.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using myetherwallet.com instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything worked for me when I went to the console in the geth client, whether there's an issue with the Mist wallet I don't know.